# How do "correctly" sync millions of files with rsync and inotify?

Tags: rsync, inotify

Assume I have 1 million files, the file list would be something like 20MB. If I add just one file, `inotify` will tell `rsync` to transfer the file list and the new file. My network is not good and I might have to limit the bandwidth (`--bwlimit`).

Multiple files might be added at once and, given the network transfer speed, there may be multiple rsyncs running at once.

Is it worth it? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your case sounds exactly what [lsyncd](https://github.com/lsyncd/lsyncd) was made for.
It watches the directory with inotify and spawns an rsync with only the changed file(s).
It aggregates changes for a few seconds.
So when you make 5 changes in one second it will only spawn one new sync process to the destination server(s).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried lsyncd and it suits me.

Comment: @seanlook how is performance with 1 million files?

Comment: @gcb I got a setup with a pretty decent server and >1 million folders(not that lsyncd watches folders, not files!) and it took ~2 days to even do the full startup sync, the low single-threaded inotify_add_watch performance seeming to be the limiting factor.